# Why can't my docker container app communicate with container couchbase database?

Tags: java, docker, couchbase

So I have a clone of the java application, and an active couchbase database, everything on my local machine. When I run the java spring application, everything works well, the application will connect to the database.

On the other hand, I use the same project and database configurations using docker containers. But I can't seem to make them communicate, and when the app starts, I keep getting this exception:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:8091
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:223)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:285)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:589)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:513)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:427)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:399)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:140)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I also created a docker network where I put the app and database.

Any idea why there is no connectivity ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you try to connect to container's `localhost`

> java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused:
>   localhost/127.0.0.1:8091

But you need to connect to another container. If you run docker container with argument `--link mysql:mysql` you need to specify into app configuration file connect to `mysql` instead of `localhost` of `127.0.0.1`